# The difference between save-current-buffer and save-selected-window

Tags: buffers, window

Consider:

```
(defun test()
  (interactive)
  (save-selected-window
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "Test buffer.")))
```

When `test` is run interactively while in a buffer visiting a file, the buffer is successfully restored. Why doesn't the following do the job?

```
(defun test()
  (interactive)
  (save-current-buffer
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "Test buffer.")))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it ***does*** successfully restore the buffer that was current, as the newly current buffer.  Try this:

```
(defun test()
  (interactive)
  (save-current-buffer
    (switch-to-buffer-other-window "Test buffer."))
  (message "current: %S" (current-buffer)))
```

`current-buffer` is not related to any particular window.  The buffer that is displayed in the (newly) selected window is buffer `Test buffer.`. But the *current* buffer is the original buffer - the one that was saved and restored by `save-current-buffer`.

Don't confuse the current buffer with a buffer that is currently displayed. You'll see the same behavior if you use `switch-to-buffer` instead of `switch-to-buffer-other-window`, in your test function. The buffer that is *displayed* is `Test buffer.`. But the `current-buffer` is the saved-and-restored buffer that was originally current.

See the Elisp manual, node [Current Buffer](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html).

Comment: Does this boil down to the difference between *selecting* a buffer and *switching* to one?

Comment: Yes, kind of. Switching to a buffer displays it in a given window, and it selects that window. If you use `switch-to-buffer` in your function, you will still see the message saying that the original buffer is current *after* the buffer-switching and the `save-current-buffer`. But after that, if you evaluate `M-: (current-buffer)` with that window selected, it will tell you that the value is `Test buffer.`, because that is the buffer that is current in the selected window.

Comment: IOW, the original buffer was current when your `test` function finished, but after that, if you check the value of `current-buffer` anew, in that window, the value is `Test buffer.`. So it is about the difference between setting the current buffer (we don't say "select" a buffer) and displaying a buffer. When you select a window and check the current buffer, the buffer displayed in that window is current.

Answer (score 1):

The `save-current-buffer` macro saves only the current buffer and restores it, unlike the `save-selected-window` macro, which saves selected windows in each frame.

The function `switch-to-buffer-other-window` doesn't affect the currently selected buffer, but the one in the next window, hence `save-current-buffer` doesn't restore the buffer selected in it.

Comment: The documentation of `save-current-buffer` says: "Record which buffer is current; execute BODY; make that buffer current." This implies to me that the original buffer should become current again. I don't understand from your answer why this does not happen.

Comment: That applies to the current buffer (which is in the window that's active.)